# How-To Login to your server with an SSH Session?

Tags: linux, php, ssh

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-zend-optimizer-in-linux-server-t82.html

I am trying to install zend optimizer. It's a pain - I've been trying for 3 days!!

```
Login to your server with an SSH Session
```

How do I do that?

And un-tar it (like it says in the install guide)?

I have GoDaddy Linux hosting account, with PHP 4.xx configuration!

Comment: Which operating system are you using on your home system (not the server). You'll need an ssh client to connect, putty for windows or just `ssh` in linux, os x, etc.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to ensure that SSH access is enabled at your service provider (in your case, GoDaddy - see [this URL](http://web.archive.org/web/20100315164454/http://help.godaddy.com/article/135)).

Then, if you are on Windows, you will need to download a program called [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). It is the most popular SSH program for Windows.

If you are on Linux or OSX, they usually have SSH built in (just run *ssh*)

Once you are logged in to your server (using the details that GoDaddy give you) you should be able to follow the instructions on that page.

However, by the looks of the software you're trying to install, it won't install on shared hosting, only a dedicated server (but I could be wrong).

Comment: the provided link is broken

Comment: @LuAndre not any more :)

Answer (score 3):

http://help.godaddy.com/article/135 -> How do I access my Linux dedicated server using SSH?

untar a file: tar xvf filename.tar
if it's tar.gz then: tar zxvf filename.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

If you run windows: you can use a nice ssh client named [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)
If you have cygwin or your are on a linux box you can type this on a console

```
ssh login@server -p port
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) if you are on Windows or [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) if you are on a different operation system. If you are not using Windows there is a big chance that you already have the ssh client installed. In this case try ssh *Nameofyouserver* -L *Loginname* in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To continue what mezgani just said, if you want to send your files to your server, you have to do :

scp -P port /file/to/send yourRemotelogin@yourServer:/the/Path

ex : scp -P 2340 c:/zend.tar.gz johan@myserver.com:/home/jonh/

then if you want to extract :

connect to the server then :

tar -zxvf zend.tar.gz